# Export specific attribute value of all xml nodes to another file

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet, xmllint

I have an `XML` document with such structure:

```
<root>
    <parent id="idvalue1" attr1="val1" attr2="val2" ...>
        <child attr3="val3" attr4="val4" ... />
        <child attr3="val5" attr4="val6" ... />
        ...
    </parent>
    <parent id="idvalue2" attr1="val7" attr2="val8" ... />
    ...
</root>
```

I want to get a list of all the values of the `id` attributes of all the nodes which have it. For now it's safe to assume that only the second level elements will have the `id` attribute.

In any case, what would be the optimal way to do this? is it `xmllint`, `xpath` or `xmlstarlet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xmlstarlet to output a list:

```
    xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//@id" yourfile.xml
```

This will output the ID values only, however.

The -t option "creates" an XSLT like suggested in Abel's answer. But the output will only be what you select with the `sel` command. The option -v is to print the value of the xpath in quotes. The double slash in the xpath expression calls for all nodes.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get a list of all the values of the id attributes of all the nodes which have it.

With XPath, you can use an expression like as follows:

```
//@id
```

which I think is quite easy. If you want some layout, you can use XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//@*" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@id">
    <xsl:text>Id is: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
```

which will give you a newline separated list of all attributes with name `id`.